# How to set a working directory to a cmake target in VSCode?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

I have a pure cmake project where I work on it from Linux (makefiles) and Windows (Visual Studio) environments.

And I want to be able to specify a kind of working directory to one of my targets so that I could read input files with relative path.

My project tree is something like:

```
App/
  src/
    code.cpp
  assets/
    image.png
build/
CMakeLists.txt
```

My App target is build at build directory and my program think that there is the starting directory (obviously).

I want to be able to load my `image.png` inside my code as:

```cpp
stbi_load("assets/image.png");
```

Instead as I am doing now:

```cpp
stbi_load("../App/assets/image.png");
```

In CLion, there is setting called "Working directory" that works exactly as I want, but I don't know how to set this directly to my CMake configuration. Or better saying, I don't know how CLion do this.

[image: CLion working directory]

To be clearer, I develop using VSCode, I worked on CLion for a long time and I remembered this setup.

Comment: `CMake` itself has no control at all of the working directory when you debug code in an IDE. Your IDE may have a setting or you could change the working directory in your c++ code.

Comment: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/current_path)

Comment: This isn't necessarily the build system's problem... why not code your application to load assets from a different directory as specified by a configuration file (which CMake could generate in the build tree), a command line argument (which your IDE and/or CTest could set), or even an environment variable? If you simply _refuse_ to do that, then re-create the necessary structure in the build directory.